# jhipster and Ui-select phantom input field

Tags: angularjs, ui-select

I have a input field showing up on my ui-select and I cant seem to be able to make it go away...
[image: input field]

Im using jhipster (latest version) angularjs, and sprigboot.

```
angular
    .module('incidenteApp', [
        'ngStorage',
        'tmh.dynamicLocale',
        'pascalprecht.translate',
        'ngResource',
        'ngCookies',
        'ngAria',
        'ngCacheBuster',
        'ngFileUpload',
        'ui.bootstrap',
        'ui.bootstrap.datetimepicker',
        'ui.router',
        'infinite-scroll',
        // jhipster-needle-angularjs-add-module JHipster will add new module here
        'angular-loading-bar',
        'lr.upload',
        'ngSanitize',
        'ui.select'

    ])
```

the html in case I have some error here...

```
  <ui-select ng-model="vm.biometrico.provincia" theme="bootstrap" title="Elegir Provincia">
            <ui-select-match placeholder="Elegir una provincia">{{$select.selected.provincia}}</ui-select-match>
            <ui-select-choices repeat="provincia in vm.provincias._embedded.provincia | filter: $select.search">
              <span ng-bind-html="provincia.provincia | highlight: $select.search"></span>
            </ui-select-choices>
            <ui-select-no-choice>
              Discula, no pudimos encontrar lo que estas buscando...
            </ui-select-no-choice>
          </ui-select>
```

Comment: Did you insert the ui-select css ? and the select bootstrap theme css ?

Comment: Added the https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/selectize.js/0.8.5/css/selectize.bootstrap3.css

css for the selectize theme and now i can scroll but it still displays a input field blank for no reason. ill edit the post

Answer (score 0):

Fixed, I was running an older version of the ui-select that was not compatible with angular1.5.8.